# TeXstudio auto-completes command not as desired

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

I'm using TeXstudio and a package I've written, which includes a command called `\co`. I've told TeXstudio to use the corresponding .cwl file and it recognizes `\co` as a command.

Here is the problem: When I type `\co{`, it gets completed to `\contentsline{`. 
How do I change this behavior?

---

In case somebody is wondering: I use `\co` *very* often, so it deserves such a simple name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a file `%APPDATA%\texstudio\myPackage.cwl` which contains the only line

```
\co
```

and safe that as utf8.

When I insert `\usepackage{myPackage}` to my preamble, it works as expected.

---

If your package is on CTAN, you might want to send your complete `myPackage.cwl`to the TXS team. To do so, just create an entry in the [feature request tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/) and attach the file.